# How to detect the next free column in a excel workbook with c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a excel template with one sheet.
The first two columns have headers and data in it.
So I can only start writing on the next column.
Every day of the month, I write data to the next available column.
So, How can I detect which is the next available column, ie, with no data?
Rui Martins

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CurrentRegion` property to get the index of the last used column, then add one to it.  My excel interop C# is a little weak, so here it is in VBA, to illustrate the object model:

```
Function FirstFreeColumn(w As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = w.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion
    FirstFreeColumn = r.Columns(r.Columns.Count).Column + 1
End Function
```

Here it is in C#, but no guarantee that this is totally correct:

```
int FirstFreeColumn(Worksheet w)
{
    var range = w.Cells[1, 1].CurrentRegion;
    var lastColumnIndex = range.Columns[range.Columns.Count].Column;
    return lastColumnIndex + 1;
}
```

Comment: I tried that before, I always get a number of 68 when I only have 3 used.

Comment: @ruimartins Aha, that would be because there was at some point a value somewhere in column 67.  The UsedRange doesn't automatically shrink when you delete data.  Use the `CurrentRegion` property instead; I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reserve a cell where you record the column you wrote your data in last time. Then before you store your data get the value add one and that's the available column.